# Resource failed to call close when access Health Connect data on Android

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm trying to access Health Connect data using the following function :

```
suspend fun readStepsByTimeRange(
    healthConnectClient: HealthConnectClient,
    startTime: Instant,
    endTime: Instant
) {
    val response =
        healthConnectClient.readRecords(
            ReadRecordsRequest(
                StepsRecord::class,
                timeRangeFilter = TimeRangeFilter.between(startTime, endTime)
            )
        )
    for (stepRecord in response.records) {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

When `readRecords` is called... my app crashes and I'm getting "A resource failed to call close." error. Can anyone think what might be going wrong?

Here's the stack trace :

```
D/StrictMode: StrictMode policy violation: android.os.strictmode.LeakedClosableViolation: A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. Callsite: close
        at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidCloseGuardReporter.report(StrictMode.java:1992)
        at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.warnIfOpen(CloseGuard.java:338)
        at sun.nio.fs.UnixSecureDirectoryStream.finalize(UnixSecureDirectoryStream.java:580)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:319)
        at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.runInternal(Daemons.java:306)
        at java.lang.Daemons$Daemon.run(Daemons.java:140)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, would you be kind enough to post the entire stack trace?

Comment: Hi @BearDroid... I've added that now. Hope you can help.